# Exception trying to clone database with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm using Spring Hibernate to clone a new MySQL database (by utilizing the structure of an existing one), but my code, shown here is throwing the exception shown below. Any ideas why this is happening?

---

```
String existingDb = "SHOW TABLES IN crm_prod";
String dbName = "NewDb";
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE DATABASE " + dbName);

SqlRowSet result = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(existingDb);
while(result.next()) {
    String tableName = result.getString(result.getMetaData().getColumnName(1)); 
    jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE "+dbName+"." + tableName + 
         " LIKE crm_prod." + tableName); 
}
```

---

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad    SQL grammar [SHOW TABLES IN crm_prod]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'TABLE_NAMES' in information_schema
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:91)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:419)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:474)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(JdbcTemplate.java:515)
at Tester.main(Tester.java:43)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'TABLE_NAMES' in information_schema
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1062)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4226)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4158)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2834)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2783)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1569)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Field.getCollation(Field.java:491)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData.isCaseSensitive(ResultSetMetaData.java:569)
at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.initMetaData(CachedRowSetImpl.java:722)
at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.populate(CachedRowSetImpl.java:639)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.createSqlRowSet(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:82)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.extractData(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:65)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.extractData(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:46)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:463)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:408)
... 3 more
```

Comment: So what is stopping you from writing code to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright adding proper data to sort it out :
From DatabaseMetadata you can extract details like tables & columns.

```
    String   catalog          = null;
    String   schemaPattern    = null;
    String   tableNamePattern = null;
    String[] types            = null;
    String   columnNamePattern = null;

    DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = con.getMetaData();
    result = databaseMetaData.getTables(catalog, schemaPattern, tableNamePattern, types );
    while(result.next()) {
        String tableName =result.getString(3);
        result1= databaseMetaData.getColumns(catalog, schemaPattern, tableName, columnNamePattern); 
        while(result1.next()) {
            String columnName = result1.getString(4);
            String    columnType = result1.getString(6);            
        }
    }
For More info : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/databasemetadata.html
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14761158)

Comment: Updated the initial Answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved the target by following code.

```
SqlRowSet createTable = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(
                "SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='" + cloneDBName + "'");
        while (createTable.next()) {
            String tableName = createTable.getString(createTable.getMetaData().getColumnName(3));
            jdbcTemplate
                    .execute("CREATE TABLE " + dbName + "." + tableName + " LIKE " + cloneDBName + "." + tableName);
        }
```